# Set up a proxy between multiple user machines and Okta for authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, proxy, spring-security-oauth2, okta

We are using Okta Customer Identity with our application.  The challenge with our architecture is that each user gets their own server and subdomain, which is a little weird for Okta, because each redirect URL needs to be provided as part of the application configuration.  As we add new users, the list of redirect URLs continues to grow, one per user machine.  Their API is not really designed for this, so we have to write the complete list of redirect URLs with every change.

We would like to find a way to use a proxy for the Okta authentication, so that we can just have a single redirect URL for the Okta application configuration.  But we're using https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot, and we're not really sure how to make it work with a proxy.

If we set up an HTTP proxy using `-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.host -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`, that's going to affect *all* HTTP traffic, which is not acceptable.

1. Is there a way we can use an HTTP proxy purely for the Okta auth only, leaving all other HTTP traffic unproxied?
2. Is there something we can do with the Okta Spring Boot library that would make it possible for all user machines to share a common proxy machine?
3. The final alternative would be to write some "active" proxy code that runs on the proxy which handles the requests and forwards them on to Okta.  It would have to introspect the Okta response and pass it back to the right user machine.

Is there a way to do #1?

Failing that, is there a way to do #2?

If neither of those are possible, are you aware of an existing implementation of #3?